# How do I create/delete item in my DB via API in Cypress?

Tags: api, automated-tests, cypress

Can you please give some more examples how do I skip UI and fill in DB with API calls in Cypress?
I am rather new to Cypress, and can't find a solution myself.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We need more information. Do you want to make a request to a API?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress is only going to help you with

> ... anything that runs in a browser

You need to design this API layer for your test harness. Put simply, [Back Door manipulation](http://xunitpatterns.com/Back%20Door%20Manipulation.html) and [Fixture Setup patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html) is what your looking for. Combining both will improve the automation UI suites.  Adding and reusing such API layer will make your suites fit enough to be part of the product’s daily life, not counting on heavy nightly regressions.

More details in [my post](http://automationisking.blogspot.com/2015/10/back-door-manipulation-api-layer.html) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited amount of information you gave us I am taking a calculated guess on this. First you can easily call an API with .request(). With that you could have your API do whatever it wants to the DB. I am not sure what you mean by SKIP UI. You want to test that so you can't SKIP it, but you could mock the API returns to fill in the information you want.